# How to compile aspx pages with cruise control.net

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net, aspnet-compiler

I have setup Cruise Control.Net 1.6.7981.1 for a ASP.Net project. It is currently building correctly with MSBuild. The MSBuild config file is setup as follows

```
<msbuild>
    <executable>c:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe</executable>
    <workingDirectory>C:\MyProject\trunk</workingDirectory>
    <projectFile>MyProject.sln</projectFile>
    <buildArgs>/t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release /v:m</buildArgs>
    <targets>Clean;Build</targets>
    <timeout>1200</timeout>
</msbuild>
```

I believe that because I the Configuration is set to release, the aspx pages are being compiled as part of the build. However if I remove the `asp:ScriptManager` tag from a page that requires it to run the build still succeeds, even though when the page loads it results in the following error.

> The control with ID 'MyControl'
>   requires a ScriptManager on the page.
>   The ScriptManager must appear before
>   any controls that need it.

Even when I manually with

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_compiler -v / -c -errorstack -p C:\MyProject\trunk\MyProject
```

the page still builds without any errors.

I really want cruise control to fail the build if any errors have made it to the build. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: It sounds like that's an ASP.NET runtime error not a compile time error - are you sure you can catch it? You could get CruiseControl to use Selenium to run a link-spider test on your deployed site - we've included this in our unit tests so CC calls nunit as part of the build and nunit runs the test.

Comment: @Rup it well be a run time error, but I would have thought it should be a compile time error. Does Selenium deal with pages that require a login?

Comment: Yes, Selenium automates a real browser e.g. Firefox - so you just have to script it to fill in the login form first. (This does mean you need to have an interactive session on your CI server though so that the browser has a desktop to run on.)

Comment: @Rup How do you integrate Selenium with Cruise Control.Net, do you just export the code to create a unit test? Do you know of any articles or blog posts about setting up Selenium with Cruise Control.Net?

Comment: I don't, sorry - someone else on the team set it up. What we've got is a few classes in our (nUnit-based) unit test project that reference ThoughtWorks.Selenium.Core/IntegrationTests/UnitTests assemblies; in our test fixture setup we create a new DefaultSelenium object and start it then open the app homepage with a 60 second timeout, and obviously stop this browser object in the TeardownTest. In tests in this class you can then load individual pages, read all the links off the page and spider them, checking at each point you don't get a "Server Error" message or similar on the page just loaded

Comment: @Rup thanks for that, at least I have somewhere to start :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that this error is runtime. The control is most likely dynamically searching for an instance of the script manager and throwing an exception when it does not find one. The compiler can only resolve issues like bad or missing references, or methods being called that don't exist.